# "Prove" that $ \int {f(x)-g(x)\ dx} = \int {f(x) \ dx} - \int {g(x)\ dx} $ by drawing (probably function's graph)

Tags: integration, geometry, graphing-functions

My teacher shown me some analysis problems which can be intuitively proved geometrically (and are simple to remeber).

I am trying to prove geometrically that:

$$ \int {f(x)-g(x)\ dx} = \int {f(x) \ dx} - \int {g(x)\ dx} $$

but I think I can't.

If I am trying to draw a random function graph for $f(x)$ and a random one for $g(x)$ and then trying to draw $f(x)-g(x)$ graph I don't reach any conlusion or what to do next.

Can it be "proved" (to understand why 
$ \int {f(x)-g(x)\ dx} = \int {f(x) \ dx} - \int {g(x)\ dx} $) by drawing? And how?

(For definite or indefinite integrals)

Thank you!

Comment: For definite integrals, it can be proven certainly. But indefinite integration does not require that equality.

Comment: Tank you for your comment. How can be proved for definite integrals? Thank you!!!

Comment: $\int f - \int g$ can be viewed as the difference in the areas under $f$ and $g$ respectively. $\int(f-g)$ can be viewed as the [signed] area between the functions $f$ and $g$. [All these statements are for definite integrals  on some interval $[a,b]$.]

Answer (score 0):

This is not generally true. However, it is true if you have definite integrals. Therefore I will change the question slightly to proving that:
\begin{align*}
\int_a^bf(x)-g(x)\ \mathrm{d}x = \int_a^bf(x)\ \mathrm{d}x - \int_a^b g(x)\ \mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
First, draw a "random" function for $f(x)$, between $a < x < b$, along with a "random" function for $g(x)$, between $a < x < b$, and $f(x)-g(x)$ between $a$ and $b$.

Then $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)$ is the "area under the graph of $f(x)$ between $a$ and $b$", while $\int_{a}^{b}g(x)$ is the "area under the graph of $g(x)$ between $a$ and $b$". By looking at your pictures you should be able to convince yourself that for any well behaved function defined between $a$ and $b$, the difference between these two areas is equal to the area under the graph of $f(x) - g(x)$. This "proves" your question.

Comment: Can you give me an example of where it is not true for indefinite integrals? I thought I have seen it proved in elementary calculus texts, for example the second proof in these notes: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/ProofIntProp.aspx

Comment: @user100000000000000 The constant of integration can be arbitrary